# SQL count NULL cells

Tags: sql, null, database

I have the following problem. I have a table in a db, with many columns. I can do different kind of select queries, to show, for example, for each record that satisfies a condition:

- all cells from columns with names ending in _t0
- all cells from columns with names ending in _t1
- ...

To get the column lists to form the queries I use the information schema.

Now, the problem: each query returns a record with a subset of the columns of the big table. This means that I can get a row of (all!) NULLs. How can I ask my query to reject such rows without having to type in explicitely the column names (i.e. by saying where col_1 is not null, col_2 is not null...)? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!!!

Sep

Comment: Which database system are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: Do you have a Primary Key on that table?

Comment: [General observation] Tables with oodles of columns raise alarm bells for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same, and I don't think it's possible.

The only decent solution seems to be to name them, from [Bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/83307-sql-statement-count-null-values):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN patientid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN age IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN weight IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN height IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+
CASE WHEN race IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tblPatientDemographics
```

Of course that's no fun, so I wrote some dynamic SQL to do this for me.  Hardly elegant, but I'm not sure there's a better way.

```
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqltail VARCHAR(MAX)
-- loop through all the fields in a table.
DECLARE @colName SYSNAME
SET @tableName = 'YourTableName'
DECLARE crsCol CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  name
    FROM    syscolumns
    WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
    ORDER BY colid
OPEN crsCol
SET @sql = ''
SET @sqltail = 'FROM [' + @tableName + ']'
FETCH NEXT FROM crsCol INTO @colName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        IF @sql = ''
            SET @sql = 'SELECT /* Add Your PK Fields here, */ NullCount = '
        ELSE 
            SET @sql = @sql + '+ '

        SET @sql = @sql + 'CASE WHEN [' + @colName + '] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END '

        FETCH NEXT FROM crsCol INTO @colName
    END
CLOSE crsCol
DEALLOCATE crsCol
PRINT (@sql + @sqltail)
EXEC(@sql + @sqltail)
```